# What is the oldest known reference to "The Circle Game"?

Tags: game

[**The Circle Game**](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=The%20Circle%20Game)] is certainly much older than the Baby Boomers, being already a boys' standard in Middle School when I arrived in the 1960's. But what is the oldest known reference to it (or a reasonably clear antecedent, though it's hard to get much simpler)?

> The game starts out when the Offensive Player creates a circle with their thumb and forefinger, not unlike an "A-Okay" signal, somewhere below his waist.
>
> His goal is to trick another person into looking at his hand. If the Victim looks at the hand, he has lost the game, and is subsequently hit on the bicep with a closed fist, by the offensive player.
>
> ....
>
> It is customary to playfully "wipe off the hit" after it is delivered. (Quick open hand brush on the bicep.)

---

#### Update:

1. I first encountered this game in 1966 or 1967 in Southern Ontario.
2. This is the game seen being played by a few Army and Navy Cadet spectators in [last Saturday's (2019-12-14) Army-Navy football game](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/us-news/military-investigates-possible-white-supremacist-gestures-students-during-army-navy-n1102366) making the *circle symbol* on national television (over announcer's right ear).

   [image]
3. I have seen several mentions on Twitter over the weekend (no region information) about it being played in Middle and High School elsewhere in North America, and by groups of U.S. Marine enlisted men, over the past half century.
4. It is also sometimes called the "Made You Look Game" with the same rules.
5. Although in Middle School I saw it occasionally used as a means of bullying weaker students, by High School I saw it exclusively played by the *jocks* as a game of one-up-man-ship amongst themselves.
6. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j2oFAin-jxQ) is the game being played on a **Malcolm in the Middle** episode (year unknown)

Comment: This is the first reference I've ever seen, so it would seem to be a regional thing.  Your mention of middle school suggests you're in the US, but it might help to add some location info.

Comment: I can confirm that it was annoyingly common where I grew up (north eastern Italy), so it's not just a US thing.

Comment: @DenisNardin: What approximate year?

Comment: I'm too young for it to be relevant to this question :) Let's say mid nineties

Comment: @DenisNardin: Data is never worthless. Tracking the spread of the game might assist someone else in finding the next link.

Comment: We did this in Bavaria in the late 90’s/early 2000’s with an elaborate set of rules on when you would be hit, when you could return the hit and such. However, early to mid-90’s in southern England I did not learn about this game.

Comment: An article [here](https://www.ranker.com/list/story-behind-circle-game/donn-saylor) discusses someone claiming to have 'invented' it in the 80s.

Comment: The Stone Age? Or so this [Quora post](https://www.quora.com/Where-does-the-circle-game-come-from) somewhat improbably claims. There's a link to *The Official Circle Game* as the source but it's broken.

Comment: @justCal: I can assure everyone that my shoulder is an honest witness to the game's existence in the mid-1960's.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I wasn't debating your recollection, just pointing to a disparity concerning the information available. Like jamesqf I also had never heard of this before (my school days were 70's in Minnesota).

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens: Where, though?  Never encountered it in rural northeast US in '60s-70s (school days), or as an adult in other parts of the country.  (Or parts of Europe, but as a visitor/temporary resident that's perhaps not surprising.)

Comment: @jamesqf: Where what? As specified in the question I attended middle school in Southern Ontario. This game has appeared on national TV in the U.S. on a long-running show, and been attested to in Italy about the same time period.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens: I didn't notice your update before writing that.  And while it may have appeared on US TV, I do have better things to do (at least IMHO :-)) than watch TV.

Comment: @jamesqf: I never watched the show either - that clip was pointed out to me by others.

Comment: In addition to the regular difficulties involved in researching aspects of children's culture, this is rather hard to research because "circle game" is also a generic term for children's games played in circles and "The Circle Game" is the name of a Margaret Atwood poem published in 1966.

Comment: I was just pointing out some confounding factors I'd encountered while researching this topic that other people might not be aware of? Because this section is for helping people answer the question?

Comment: @WiJaMa: Fair enough - comment deleted.